# Keep a progress dialog opened when I press back button from and intent ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS

Tags: android, android-intent, progressdialog

I am going to try to explain this better because the title is not too clear.

I show a `ProgressDialog` in my main `activity` when I start my application which is shown for 2 minutes while I am trying to get user location. I don't require user to get GPS enabled because sometimes Android can get user location withouth GPS (wifi, last know location...) but when GPS is not enabled I show a button on the `ProgressDialog` which let user enable it (`Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS` `Intent`).

Here comes the problem. I press the `button` to go to settings to active GPS but when I press back button to go to my `activity`, the `progressdialog` is not shown anymore though it is still trying to get user location, so it seems applications is not doing anything even though it is still looking for user location.

Is there a possibility to show that `dialog` again when I come back from settings? I wouldn't want to start the dialog again, I would like to resume previous one. This way it wouldn't take 2 minutes again to finish it.

This is my code:

MyLocationProvider.java:

```
final ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(activity);
progress.setMessage("Getting Location");
progress.setIndeterminate(true);
progress.setCancelable(false);
if (!checkGpsEnabled.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
    progress.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "Enable GPS", 
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {                                                        
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                activity.startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    );
}
progress.show();
```

I would appreciate any help. Thanxs a lot.

**EDIT 1**

I have made a test on my `MainActivity` and it seems a `ProgressDialog` should still be shown when you come back from another `Activity`:

```
ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
pDialog.setCancelable(false);
pDialog.show();
```

I have added this code on `onCreate` and it is shown when I press back button from `Settings Activity`, while `ProgressDialog` from `MyLocationProvider` dissapears.

Comment: check the onresume() ,current location lat and long have available or null.if it's get location don't show the progress or it's null show the progress.

Comment: This is not an Activity actually, it is MyLocationProvider.class which implements an onFinish() interface and it is called from MainActivity.class.